# Move cursor from the beginning of a highlight to end of highlight

Tags: vim

I have the following sentence:

> I want to add api restriction to MsrestHandler and RESTHandler.
>
> ~

(~ indicates the cursor position)

I want to change `MsrestHandler` to `MsRESTHandler`.

Because the search in my VIM is case insensitive, one way I think of is to use search, ie. type <kbd>/rest</kbd>. Then VIM shows

> I want to add api **rest**riction to Ms**rest**Handler and
>   **REST**Handler.

(bold text show the matches and highlight)

Then I press n twice to move cursor to the second match. I know <kbd>gU</kbd> with a motion can make the text upper case, but what command do I have to move cursor from `r` to `t`?

I don't want to count characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relatively recent `gn` was created specifically for that purpose:

```
gnU
```

Used as a normal mode command, `gn` visually selects the closest search match. If the cursor is on a match, the current match is selected, if not, the cursor jumps to the next match and selects it.

Used as a motion in visual mode, `gn` expands the selection to cover the whole current match if the cursor is on a match or to the next search match if it's not.

Used as an operator-pending motion, `gn` makes the command operate on the current match or the next match following the same logic as above.

Of course, you also have the mirrored `gN`.

Comment: This is what I want!

Answer (score 1):

The motion command you want to look at is `f`:

```
:help f
```

For example, you would do `gUft` to accomplish what you asked in your example.

Comment: But it won't work if there is another t between the begin of the match and the end of the match.

Comment: So add a count: gU2ft